# add Listener to logger context in logback

Tags: logback

I have the following code for adding a listener to my logger context:

```
private static void configureLoggerContext(String logbackConfigFileUrl) {
    File file = new File(logbackConfigFileUrl);
    LoggerListener loggerListener = new LoggerListener();
    LoggerContext loggerContext = (LoggerContext) LoggerFactory.getILoggerFactory();
    loggerContext.reset();
    loggerContext.addListener(loggerListener);
    JoranConfigurator configurator = new JoranConfigurator();
    configurator.setContext(loggerContext);
    try {
        configurator.doConfigure(file);
    } catch (JoranException je) {
        throw new RuntimeException(je.getMessage());
    }
}
```

Is there anyway so that I won't have to doConfigure after adding listener?
My problem is that I have added a  and because two times configuration, my header is printed twice.